# Can you test models with no functions?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

This isn't a question that I'm asking because something is broken. It is more along the lines of I'd like to know what to do in this situation.

If I have written the following model,

```
class Amenity extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Amenity';
     /**
     * Behaviors used by the Model
     *
     * @var array
     * @access public
     */

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'RoomFlat' =>
                array(
                     'className'              => 'RoomFlat',
                     'joinTable'              => 'amenities_room_flats',
                     'foreignKey'             => 'amenity_id',
                     'associationForeignKey'  => 'room_flat_id',


                )
        ); 

    var $actsAs = array(        
        'Multivalidatable'
    );  
    /**
     * Custom validation rulesets
     */ 
    var $validationSets = array(
       'admin'=>array(
          'name'=>array(                        
             'notEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'message'=>'This  is required'        
                        ),
             'isUnique'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'isUnique',
                        'message'=>'This already exists.'
                        )   
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

and I have also written the following fixture

```
class AmenityFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'name' => array('type' => 'text', 'null' => 'false'),
        'status' => array('type' => 'tinyint', 'null' => 'false'),
        'created' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => 'false'),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => 'false')
    );

    public function init(){ 
        $this->records = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'amenity fixture 1', 'status'=>'1', 'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'amenity fixture 2', 'status'=>'0', 'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'amenity fixture 3', 'status'=>'1', 'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'amenity fixture 4', 'status'=>'0', 'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'amenity fixture 5', 'status'=>'1', 'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
        );
        parent::init();
    }

}
```

what would be the best way to test it? I don't really have any functions in the model to test? Is this a situation where you really wouldn't unit test anything? If you were to tell me to write a test suite for this, how would you have me do it?

I'm also using cakePHP and yes I've read the page on testing (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html). But I'm really trying to understand why something is done as opposed to how. If anyone can suggest any good books or articles, that would also help.

If I need to post any other details then just let me know.

Comment: If it doesn't have any functions - then there is nothing to test

Comment: Would I be better off just writing a test for the controller, or would it be better for me to move the logic that saves and deletes data to/from the database into to the model and moving it out of the controller?

Comment: All you *business logic* should be expressed as a model method. "Remove amenity" is one business logic task and should have its own method in the model, which you can then test using unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was pretty much answered in the comments, but here is an answer, for the sake of clarity.

This is a case where you don't have any tests for your model. Most of the time, you only need to test the public methods of an object, and you don't have any here. If you had a method like this:

```
class Amenity extends AppModel
{
    public function doSomething($one, $two, $three)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you would need to write tests with different combinations of `$one`, `$two` and `$three`. But there is no purpose in testing model functions such as `Model::find()` method, since they are covered by the cake's own tests.

In the end, I'm going to quote [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) from comments:

> All you business logic should be expressed as a model method.

This is a very important concept, both for testing and clarity.

For more info, read these: [fat models](http://bitfluxx.com/2008/01/23/cakephp-best-practices-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers.html), [skinny controllers](http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2007/04/27/fat-models-skinny-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can test those models. because actually, they DO have methods (their parent model ones).

But it would only make sense to cover the basics then (read/write). to assert that the table is correctly set up etc - so maybe some save() and find() tests.
you may also test correctly set up relations (HABTM in your case) or your validation rules.

Everything else is probably already covered by the cake tests.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Cakephp, one could/should unit-test two other aspects :

- validation rules
- models' relationships

**Why ?** because it will detect code regression *if any field name or type changes* in your models.

I especially focus on **typing** and **naming** assert() because regression does occur of course (multiple developers, multiple versions) and you will have a hard time detecting this otherwise.

Hope this helps !